# Is it possible to consume a service with worker threads in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, worker-thread

I'm coding in NodeJS, I'm trying to make an API service which use multithreading internally, I've read many worker-threads tutorials, but I haven't found a solution.

In classes/controller.js:

```
const { Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData } = require('worker_threads');
const os = require('os');
...
var threadN = function()
{
    if (isMainThread)
    {
        module.exports = function parseJSAsync(script)
        {
            return new Promise
            (
                (resolve, reject) =>
                {
                    const worker = new Worker(filename, {workerData: script});
                    worker.on('message', resolve);
                    worker.on('error', reject);
                    worker.on
                    (
                        'exit',
                        (code) =>
                        {
                            if (code !== 0)
                            {
                                reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        };
        console.log('Thread ID:       ', Worker.threadId, "\nNumber of CPU's:", os.cpus().length);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Thread ID:       ', Worker.threadId, "\nNumber of CPU's:", os.cpus().length);
        const { parse } = require('some-js-parsing-library');
        const script = workerData;
        parentPort.postMessage(parse(script));
    }
};
...
exports.threadTest = function (req, res)
{
    threadN();
    res.json
    ({
        status: true,
        message: 'Hello World!'
    });
};
```

In routes/routes.js

```
var app = express();
...
app.get("/api_1.0/threadtest", model.threadTest);
...
```

When I consume it in Postman and see console changes I must get four messages (my CPU has four cores) with four thread ids, otherwise I got this:

[image: console_response]

How can I consume an API service with worker_thread correctly?

Comment: And, to the title of your question, yes you can handle most of a route in a WorkerThread if you code it properly.

Comment: FYI, I find a coding style that uses 4-5 lines (when 1 line is the usual way) is very difficult to read and follow because of that style.  I'm curious where you got this style from?  Were you taught this somewhere?  Or you just like it?  For example: `worker.on('exit', (code) => {` would usually be on one 1 line instead of 5.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to consume a service with worker threads in NodeJS?

Yes, if the worker thread and route for calling it is written properly.

There are a number of things wrong here:

1. You call `threadN()` in your route, but all that does in the main thread is assign `parseJSAsync` to `module.exports`.  It doesn't actually call anything in another thread or even create another thread.  It doesn't call `parseJSAsync()`.
2. Assigning something to `module.exports` long after the module has been initialized is an anti-pattern that probably doesn't do anything useful.  Any importing module already looked for what it might find in the exports, long before you assigned `parseJSAsync` to it.
3. In `threadTest()`, you call `threadN()`, but that doesn't do anything useful for processing the request.  It seems more like you need to be calling `parseJSAsync()` and then using the promise that it returns.

On a personal style note, I find workerThread code a ton easier to understand and work on if I put the mainThread code and workerThread code in separate files.  Then there's no context needed within the file in order to know which code is which.  IMO, it is a ton easier to understand and follow.  I know that node.js documentation examples tend to use the single file approach, but after trying it, I moved to separate files as it was so much easier to work on, debug and understand.